# In (FIPS PUB-197) AES-128 cipher, how many unique 128 bit cipher keys are required, if my plain-text is divided into N 128 bit blocks?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric

All descriptions of the AES-128 algorithm that I've found on the inter-web talk about inputting a 128 bit plaintext that undergoes 11 rounds of transformations to produce a 128 bit cipher text. My question is:

**Since the actual message to be sent can occupy more than just a single 128 bit "block", do I need a unique key for each 128 bit block that I generate from my message to be encrypted using AES-128, or can I use the same key for each of those 128 bit blocks?**

I need this information in regards to creating an algorithm for a paper (journal), so I need to be scientifically correct in my use of AES-128, which forms a part of my algorithm.

Comment: [How can I encrypt more than 128 bits of data with AES?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51477/how-can-i-encrypt-more-than-128-bits-of-data-with-aes)

Comment: Long story short, you use a [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) to turn a block cipher like AES into a stream cipher.

Comment: As others have said, you need a cypher mode.  You will only need one key.  Use either CBC mode or CTR mode if you do not require authentication.  For authentication use GCM mode.  You will also likely need padding for the last block of your message.  Unless you have a reason not to, use PKCS#7 padding.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Block_cipher_mode_of_operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

If you use the same key for every block, you are using the Electronic codebook (ECB). However this mode of operation is not recomended.

Something more secure would be the Galois/Counter mode or the Cipher block chaining mode. For more information read the wiki article.

Comment: The answer above is a pointer to the right concept(s) for considering how to encrypt multiple blocks.  Since you're using FIPS 197 for AES, you should probably look to NIST SP800-38a through 'g' for specifications for the various "modes" of operation for AES.  ***Be very careful that there are a number of ways to attack _uses_ of cryptography*** and until you've spent quite a while understanding the basic attacks, it's very easy to accidentally expose oneself to an attack.  In the context of the so-called "wrapper modes" of AES, be sure to understand the 'padding oracle' attack at least.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with FIPS PUB-197, but I know the security properties of AES.

AES is a block cipher and all block ciphers are modeled in such a way that you cannot deduce the key even if you know both ciphertext and plaintext. With this property, you can follow that using the same key for multiple blocks is perfectly secure even if parts of the plaintext and ciphertext are known to the attacker. This property emerges after cryptanalysis that is done by cryptographers when they want to find holes in an algorithm like AES.

Also, if you have 11 rounds for a 128 bit key, you don't have AES, but something else.